# update 2 different table with just 1 button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, button

I'm trying to update 2 different table with 1 button in my web application. I'm currently using asp.net to develop my web app. I wonder if it is possible to update 2 different columns from 2 different table.

Here are my backend codes

```
 protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SqlConnection connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI");

        //connAdd.Open();
        //string mySQL;
        //mySQL = "Update LoginRegisterPoliceOfficer Set caseid ='" + lblCID.Text + "' where fullname ='" + DDLpolice.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
        //SqlCommand cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(mySQL, connAdd);
        //cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //connAdd.Close();



        SqlConnection connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI");

        connAdd.Open();
        string mySQLL;
        mySQLL = "Update Report Set handle = 'handled' where caseid='"+lblCID.Text+"'";
        SqlCommand cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(mySQLL, connAdd);
        cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connAdd.Close();


    }
```

I'm only able to update 1 but failed to update with the 2nd. Therefore i comment out one of my sql codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same database for both tables, you don't need to close and open the connection.  Use the same connection, and execute the 2 statements one after the other.

```
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
    {
        connAdd.Open();
        var sql = "Update LoginRegisterPoliceOfficer Set caseid ='" + lblCID.Text + "' where fullname ='" + DDLpolice.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
        using(var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd)) 
        {
            cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        sql = "Update Report Set handle = 'handled' where caseid='"+lblCID.Text+"'";
        using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(mySQLL, connAdd)) 
        {
              cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        connAdd.Close();
    }
}
```

the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is needed so the .NET runtime reclaims memory that could be lost when the objects are destroyed, without them your code introduces memory leaks which can affect your site's performance (among other things).

the [var statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9wtdcw1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a concise way of declaring variables.  I like to use it when the type of variable is obvious based on the right side of the `=` sign, otherwise, the code looks redundant and verbose.

finally, this code is is very prone to a [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  constructing sql with posted values can be very dangerous.  what if the value lblCID.Text is '(drop table LoginRegisterPoliceOfficer)'?  a safer way to execute queries is by using stored procedures or [sql parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  You should be able to do any number of updates inside a single ASP.NET function, provided that you don't run into a timeout or accidentally close something you wanted to leave open.

Leave the SqlConnection object open, and create two sqlCommand instances.  Or Have both of your UPDATES sent as a single string, with a line break and a semi-colon between them.  Or move the logic over to the server-side, and have a stored procedure that knows to update them both. (Could you make an updateable view?)